# Homomorphisms of abelian varieties and Tate modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ and $B$ be abelian varieties over a field $k$ and $\ell$ be a prime different from the characteristic of $k$, we have an injection $Hom(A,B) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}_\ell \to Hom (T_\ell A, T_\ell B)$, from the "isogeny $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-module" to the homomorphisms of $\ell$-adic Tate's modules. This injection is an isomorphism for some $k$ due to Tate's theorem and conjecture.

If the $Hom(A,B)$ is interpreted as the group of algebraic group homomorphisms from $A$ to $B$ (as opposed to isogenies) i.e. the homomorphisms need not be surjective with finite kernels, we still have the natural map $Hom(A,B) \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}_\ell \to Hom (T_\ell A, T_\ell B)$. I'm wondering what we can say about this map. For example, can this be injective if $B$ is an elliptic curve and $A$ is a higher dimensional abelian variety?

Comment: Suppose that $f:A\to B$ is a non-zero isogeny which induces the zero map on Tate modules. Let $g: B\to A$ be an isogeny such that the composition $B\to A \to B$ is non-zero (to see that this exists use dual isogenies). Now, the composed map $f\circ g$ induces the zero map on Tate modules which implies (by the injectivity mentioned in your first paragraph) that it is zero. Contradiction.

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar What if $f$ is not an isogeny i.e. not surjective with finite kernel?

Comment: For every possible kernel $K$ of a morphism $A\to B$, the map $\phi_K\colon {\rm Hom}(A/K,B)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}\to {\rm Hom}(T_{\ell}(A/K),T_{\ell}B)$ is injective by the Tate conjecture; and the map ${\rm Hom}(A,B)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}\to {\rm Hom}(T_{\ell}A,T_{\ell}B)$ when restricted to the image of ${\rm Hom}(A/K,B)$ in ${\rm Hom}(A,B)$, is just the composition of $\phi_K$ with the canonical map ${\rm Hom}(T_{\ell}(A/K),T_{\ell}B)\to {\rm Hom}(T_{\ell}A,T_{\ell}B)$, which is injective, because the image of $T_{\ell}A\to T_{\ell}(A/K)$ has finite index.

Comment: @wkf I wrote isogeny, but I just meant non-zero homomorphism. But then I guess my argument with "dual isogenies" is unclear. What I meant is simply to choose an isogeny $A^\vee \to A$ and an isogeny $B^\vee\to B$, and then dualize $A\to B$ to get $B\to B^\vee \to A^\vee \to A\to B$; this composed morphism is a non-zero isogeny (right?)

Comment: Sorry, another typo: I meant to write $B\to B^\vee$ (instead of $B^\vee\to B$.